# Aligning a sum of terms across multiple aligns

Tags: spacing, equations, align

The terms within the square brackets align well but I can't figure out how to shift them to the left. The LaTeX code and the output can be found below.

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
    \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} p_\infty(k) &= m(m+1) \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{2}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+2} \right)   \\
                                    &= m(m+1) \: &[ \frac{1}{m} &- \frac{2}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2}             \\
                                    & \hspace{5pt} &+ \frac{1}{m+1} &- \frac{2}{m+2} + \frac{1}{m+3}                        \\
                                    & \hspace{5pt} &+ \frac{1}{m+2} &- \frac{2}{m+3} + \frac{1}{m+4}                    \\
                                    & \hspace{5pt} &+ \frac{1}{m+3} &- \frac{2}{m+4} + \frac{1}{m+5}                  \\
                                    & \hspace{5pt} + ...    ] 
\end{alignat}
```

[image]

I have tried using double && instead but that does not work as well. How should I place the & symbols so that the terms align nicely across multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

Change the point of alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} p_\infty(k)
  &= m(m+1) &&\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{2}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+2} \right)   \\
  &= m(m+1) &&\biggl[ \frac{1}{m} - \frac{2}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2} \\
  &         &&\,+ \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{2}{m+2} + \frac{1}{m+3}     \\
  &         &&\,+ \frac{1}{m+2} - \frac{2}{m+3} + \frac{1}{m+4}     \\
  &         &&\,+ \frac{1}{m+3} - \frac{2}{m+4} + \frac{1}{m+5}     \\
  &         &&\,+ \dotsb\biggr]
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's perhaps simpler with a nested `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} p_\infty(k)
  &= m(m+1) \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{2}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+2} \right)   \\
  &= m(m+1) \begin{aligned}[t]
            \biggl[ & \frac{1}{m} - \frac{2}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2} \\
                    &+ \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{2}{m+2} + \frac{1}{m+3}     \\
                    &+ \frac{1}{m+2} - \frac{2}{m+3} + \frac{1}{m+4}     \\
                    &+ \frac{1}{m+3} - \frac{2}{m+4} + \frac{1}{m+5}     \\
                    &+ \dotsb\biggr]
            \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```